# Pandas Read Sql Duplicate Column Names

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I'm using `df = pd.read_sql(query,connect)`,
where the query is like

```
SELECT TOP 1000
  t1.*
  ,t2.*
  ,t3.*
FROM table t1
LEFT JOIN table t2 ON t1.attr1 = t2.attr1
LEFT JOIN table t3 ON t1.attr1 = t3.attr1
```

All three table have quite many attributes with attribute names that are duplicate amongst the different tables but not within the same table. Therefore I get  `ValueError: Duplicate names found`.

Is there an easy workaround without having to specify each column name?